# Оффлайн поиск текста по заголовкам на Javascript

Tags: javascript

Есть папка с HTML-Файлами. Просто папка, лежащая прямо у пользователя, без вебсервера.

Как реализовать поиск по заголовкам (h1-h6) HTML-страниц в ней?

(Желательно, чтобы запрос возвращал начальный текст после заголовка).

Спасибо!

Comment: "Есть папка с HTML-Файлами." -- просто папка прямо у клиента, или всё-таки раздаваемая вебсервером?

Comment: Да, папка у клиента.